# strip the text next to an input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Please help me with a simple question:

code:

```
<span>
<input id="elemento_20_1" name="elemento_20_1" class="elemento text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" type="text"> /
<label for="elemento_20_1">DD</label>
</span>
```

With Jquery, How can i strip down the "/" next to the input? i try .next() but didn't work at all.

Thanks!

Comment: show the code you wrote.

Comment: @Rafee: Don't overdo it. What do you expect OP to show you?

Comment: is this the html that you wrote and why do you want to strip the '/'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('span').contents().filter(function(){
   return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2AqWW/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$("span").html($("span").html().replace(" / ",""));
```

Even if I suggest not to do this with Jquery

If you want to cut only "/" without spaces then:

```
$("span").html($("span").html().replace("/",""));
```